# Why is this equivalence true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My prof used this equivalence for proofing a sequence in analysis.
Can anyone explain me how you know it is equivalent immediately?

$$
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon  \iff  \frac{1}{2\epsilon} < \sqrt{n}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $2\sqrt{n}>0$ we can multiply both sides of $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon$ with $2\sqrt{n}$ with keeping the direction of inequality:
$$
1 < 2\sqrt{n} \epsilon.
$$
And since $2\epsilon>0$ we can divide with $2\epsilon$ with keeping the direction of inequality:
$$
\frac{1}{2\epsilon} < \sqrt{n}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not advanced enought to see those transformations immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly because, under the ambiental hypothesis, $\frac{\sqrt n}{\epsilon}>0$, and therefore multiplication and division by that number on both sides preserve the inequality.

Comment: I like the adjective "ambiental", providing a romantic touch...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :)